# Trigger builds when gitlab merge requests accepted on jenkins doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-plugins

I can't find a way to trigger builds on jenkins when a gitlab merge request get accepted.

Here is my job configuration :

jenkins version : Jenkins ver. 2.107.3
gitlab version : 11.2.3

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My webhook configuration on gitlab :

[image]

I tried, to select push events and accepted MR events on jenkins side, it works but for each push !
I want to know if this is the only way to get that works (push + accepted MR events).
Logically i just have to select accepted Mr only, but i get nothing, it doesn't seems to work that way.

I checked jenkins issues and find this one, i don't know if this is the same issue ? https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/636

Can you help me please, any ideas ?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to set only 'Merge request events' in GitLab webhook configuration (as I see, you have both push and MR events).?

Comment: Yes i tried this option too. and it doesn't work!

Comment: What do you mean in phrase "doesn't work"? It's not triggered at all, or it's triggered by each push? If it's not triggered at all, maybe allowing any push event on Jenkins side can help.

Comment: I tried all possible combinations: webhook(push & accept MR events) + jenkins(pushs + accepted MR), no builds has been trigrred if jenkins(pushs not checked)

Comment: That's strange. I had the similar issue with GitHub webhooks for old Jenkins version, and the only solution I found is to recreate webhook each time after Jenkins job was changed. But seems to be that your issue is different. Anyway, I recommend you to update your Jenkins to the last LTS release (2.150.2) and GitLab plugin to 1.5.11 version.

Comment: you generated the token and added to the gitlab?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. One workaround is to trigger builds whenever there is a pushs on my Dev branch (verify if the target branch is "dev" usin bash script), if there is a push on this branch that means that this an accepted MR.  My script looks like this : if [[ ${gitlabTargetBranch} == "dev" ]];then
 echo ">>> New merge request has been accepted."
 else
   echo ">>> New push on ${gitlabSourceBranch}."
fi

Comment: As i said it's just a workaround, i don't know if upgrading jenkins and gitlab will solve the problem ! But i think there is a problem in gitlab plugin !

Comment: @mbn217 i don't have admin permissions to create webhooks, but i think the webhook is well configured.

Answer (score 0):

you have to double check because i have same scenario and it's working fine

[image: Gitlab_Integration_Setting]

Comment: can you show me your job configuration ? is pushs and accepted MR both checked or just accepted MR ? and what is your jenkins and gitlab versions ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont find any solution so far using the plugin alone, and as I read this plugin is not directly developed by gitlab, my combo solution so far is:

- to have a freestyle job, with configured webhook, where I can choose the MR events I need (Opened/Accepted/Closed) and retrieve all gitlab variables like gitlabMergeRequestState
- from this job call another job defined via a fully elaborated pipeline, passing that gitlab variables, where all needed details can be handled via gitlab API.